# java android ошибка при оформлении excel файла

Tags: java, android, apache, excel, poi

Пишу программу на android. В программе создаю excel файл. Файл создаю и заполеяю данными без проблем. НО! Когда я оформляю excel файл, программа падает(крашица, вылетает) со следующей ошибкой:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Color;
```

Часть кода:

```
    Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Tets");
    Font headerFont;
    headerFont = workbook.createFont();
    headerFont.setBold(true);
    headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 17);
    headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
    CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
```

вылетает на строчке:

```
CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
```

библиотеки:

```
implementation files('libs/poi-3.17.jar')
implementation files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.17.jar')
implementation files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar')
```

Помогите кто чем может. Спасибо, хорошего дня!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Я решил свою проблему. Все проще чем кажется.

1. Создаем новый проект;
2. Проходим по [ссылке](https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/releases) и скачиваем последнюю версию **poishadow-all.jar**;
3. Скаченную библиотеку копируем в корневую папку созданного проекта. Как показано на картинке:

[image: копируем в папку куда указывает черная стрелка]

4. Переходим в File/Project Structure/app/Dependencies/"нажимает на кнопку «зеленый крест»"/Jar Dependency/в появившемся окне в папке libs выбираем скаченную библиотеку (**poishadow-all.jar**). В конце нажимает кнопку OK и ждем завершения процессов и синхронизаций и подкачиваний.
5. В классе где создаете excel файл копируете то что написано ниже:

   ```
    System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.InputFactoryImpl");
    System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.OutputFactoryImpl");
    System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.EventFactoryImpl");
   ```
6. Пишем свой код.

Ради эксперимента вставте следующий код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.InputFactoryImpl");
        System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.OutputFactoryImpl");
        System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.EventFactoryImpl");

        try {
            writeWorkbook();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void writeWorkbook() throws java.io.IOException
    {
        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        try {
            Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");
            Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue("cell-1");
            cell = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue("cell-2");
            cell = row.createCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue("Hello");

            Font headerFont;
            headerFont = wb.createFont();
            headerFont.setBold(true);
            headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 17);
            headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());

            HSSFCellStyle style = (HSSFCellStyle) wb.createCellStyle();
            //   style.setFillBackgroundColor(new HSSFColor(new org.apache.poi.java.awt.Color(1, 2, 3)));
            style.setFillBackgroundColor((short)17);
            style.setFont(headerFont);

            Hyperlink link = wb.getCreationHelper().createHyperlink(HyperlinkType.URL);
            link.setAddress("http://www.google.at");
            link.setLabel("Google");
            cell.setHyperlink(link);

            cell.setCellStyle(style);

            sheet.setPrintGridlines(true);

        } finally {
            wb.close();
        }

        String excelFileName = "Test.xls";  //name of excel file
        FileOutputStream outputStream;

        try {
            outputStream = openFileOutput(excelFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            wb.write(outputStream);
            //   outputStream.write(cell.toString().getBytes());
            //   outputStream.close();

            File file = new File( excelFileName);
            file.getAbsolutePath();

            FileInputStream f = openFileInput(excelFileName);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Так как я проверяю на эмуляторе и сохраняю файл на внутренней памяти, открыть excel файл я могу через Device File Explorer. Итак, открываем Device File Explorer/data/data/ «ищите ваш пакет проекта»/files – там вы и увидите созданный файл.

Пользуйтесь на здоровье!!! Всем Хорошего настроения!!!